# How to generate BuildConfig file at compilation time

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm currently trying to instanciate my `BuildConfig` file during flavor selection time but I'm facing issue with it

The purpose is to be able to run the project with the less of informations possible

I'm using `build.gradle` (not `kts` for now) and I have two `buildTypes` define : `debug` and `release`

And then, I have some `productFlavors`, to simplify this, let's call them `production` and `validation` which represents two environments

Both flavor shares the same basecode, but I have a different config for each (for example baseUrl), these files (both empty when cloning project) are there :

- app/src/production/myProperties.properties
- app/src/validation/myProperties.properties

Because of security concern, some people which have access to the project doesn't need to know properties for production but only for validation

I've read a lot that we need to do something like this :

```
buildConfigField "String", "PropertyName", "PropertyValue"
```

And lot of people are defining these `buildConfigField` inside `productFlavors` block

But, by doing so, I'm forced to have both properties for `production` and `validation` during synchronization. Because gradle try each possibilities for `buildTypes` and `productFlavors`

I've also try to define `buildConfigField` during `preBuild.doFirst` (of applicationVariants), but it's too late and we can't modify `BuildConfig` during compilation time and we need it during development

In the end, the behavior I want is this one:

- Someone clone the repository, I give him the content of `myProperties` for `validation`
- He can synchronize the project, it selects the `validationDebug` by default (selection of this variant is already done with `getIsDefault().set(true)` for both `buildTypes` and `productFlavor`)
- He can build the app
- If he selects `productionDebug`, he will not be able to compile because he doesn't have `myProperties` for production

Is this possible to achieve this?

Thanks!